# Android Device default vibrate pattern

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration

I tried to vibrate my app with device's default vibration settings but i can not do it with using Vibration. I tried it code which is below.

```
 case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
         Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
         long[] pattern = { 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 2000 };
         vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

Is there any way to vibrate device with its default settings. I used the pattern but i need device incoming call default vibrate settings.

Or how can i get device's vibrate pattern?

Thanks.